# Convert 10M rows of Text with letters To Number

Tags: excel, vba, data-conversion

I need to convert "text numbers" into numbers. The text numbers look like: 32,23B or 242,23M.

I need to remove the letter and multiply by 1,000 ; 1,000,000 ; etc., depending on the letter.
The code below works, but as I need to convert 10M lines it takes ages.

Is there any clever way to do it?

```vb
For shIndex = startSheet To lastSheet
    LastRowF = Sheets(shIndex).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    For i = 3 To LastRowF
        
        Mul = Right(Sheets(shIndex).Range("F" & i), 1)
            
        Select Case Mul
            Case "K"
                Multiplier = 1
            Case "M"
                Multiplier = 1000
            Case "B"
                Multiplier = 1000000
            Case "T"
                Multiplier = 1000000000
            Case Else
                Multiplier = False
        End Select
            
        If Multiplier Then
            With Sheets(shIndex)
                .Range("F" & i) = CSng(Left(Sheets(shIndex).Range("F" & i), Len(Sheets(shIndex).Range("F" & i)) - 1) * Multiplier)
                .Range("F" & i).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
            End With
        End If
    Next i
Next shIndex
```

Comment: Have you turned off screen updating and calculations? If anything is being calculated from he resultant output that could be hanging up the macro

Comment: Load the data into `Variant` arrays and do the conversion in-memory, then write back to the sheet.

Comment: @BigBen oh no I forgot how to do this. Hoping to see you solution this so I can remember ;)

Comment: @urdearboy - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: Why not just use the built I function 'Search and replace', no need for VBA here in my opinion

Comment: @Andreas - I don't think that will work with OP's data.

Comment: Search for M, replace with '000'. If it's float values the it's a different thing. Perhaps a few examples?

Comment: See the sample data provided by OP in the first sentence @Andreas.

Comment: Didn't notice that... Not sure if regex is faster but with regex you could make it `=[number]*1000` . But I assume that is slower since I have not seen any regex possible of doing the whole sheet at once. Unless if you take the whole sheet and place it in a string then back to the sheet

Comment: @urdearboy: yes I've turned off screen as well as calculation set as manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Variant` array, do the conversion in memory, then write the entire array back to the sheet:

```
For shIndex = startSheet To lastSheet
    LastRowF = Sheets(shIndex).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Sheets(shIndex).Range("F3:F" & LastRowF).Value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(data, 1) to UBound(data, 1)
        Mul = Right(data(i, 1), 1)

        Select Case Mul
            Case "K"
                Multiplier = 1
            Case "M"
                Multiplier = 1000
            Case "B"
                Multiplier = 1000000
            Case "T"
                Multiplier = 1000000000
            Case Else
                Multiplier = False
        End Select

        If CBool(Multiplier) Then
            data(i, 1) = Left(data(i,1), Len(data(i, 1)) - 1) * Multiplier
        End 

        With Sheets(shIndex).Range("F3:F" & LastRowF)
           .Value = data
           .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With 
     
    Next
Next
```

Comment: @urdearboy - that may be a bonus actually. I begrudgingly continue to use VBA but it is so passé.

Comment: What is benefit of using `If CBool` rather `If Multiplier`?

Comment: No benefit really. Just more explicit. Maybe I should put the `CSng` (or `CDbl`) back in too.

Answer (score 2):

### Modify Number Format

- Implementing an array might do the trick.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub modifyValues()
    
    Const FirstCell As String = "F3"
    Const startSheet As Long = 1
    Const lastSheet As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Current As Variant
    Dim Multiplier As Variant
    Dim Mul As String
    Dim shIndex As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    For shIndex = startSheet To lastSheet
        With wb.Worksheets(shIndex).Range(FirstCell)
            LastRow = .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1)
        End With
        Data = rng.Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Current = Data(i, 1)
            Mul = Right(Current, 1)
            Select Case Mul
                Case "K"
                    Multiplier = 1
                Case "M"
                    Multiplier = 1000
                Case "B"
                    Multiplier = 1000000
                Case "T"
                    Multiplier = 1000000000
                Case Else
                    Multiplier = False
            End Select
            If Multiplier Then
                Data(i, 1) = CSng(Left(Current, Len(Current) - 1) * Multiplier)
            End If
        Next i
        rng.Value = Data
        rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Next shIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: BIG THANKS, this solution flies compared to mine. I've voted for your answer, but can't be seen as per my low reputation...